# Grunt connect server returns cannot GET /route with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I have a connect server running on localhost, and in my backbone app, if I reload a route, say localhost:8000/fun the server returns Cannot GET /fun obviously because /fun doesn't exist.

Somehow the server needs to know to serve index.html/fun or something. I actually tried that, but I get some other error. Has anyone dealt with this before?

**TL;DR** Cannot GET /fun

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[So the basic solution was found here.](https://gist.github.com/nnarhinen/7719157)

You want modRewrite:

```
npm install connect-modrewrite --save-dev
```

And in your Gruntfile:

```
modRewrite = require('connect-modrewrite')
```

Coffee:

```
connect:
  server:
    options:
      port: 8765
      open: true
      base: ['./']
      middleware: (connect, options) ->
        middlewares = []

        middlewares.push(modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']))
        options.base.forEach( (base) ->
          middlewares.push(connect.static(base))
        )
        middlewares
```

Vanilla JS:

```
connect: {
  server: {
    options: {
      port: 8765,
      open: true,
      base: ['./'],
      middleware: function(connect, options) {
        var middlewares;
        middlewares = [];
        middlewares.push(modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']));
        options.base.forEach(function(base) {
          return middlewares.push(connect["static"](base));
        });
        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer didn't work anymore (2015-10-20), because there were changes to connect project-structure and connect.static was moved to its own package 'serve-static'. So you have to adapt this answer by the following:

```
npm install serve-static --save-dev
```

require it in your Gruntfile.js

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
```

and then change the middleware code to following:

```
middleware: function(connect, options) {
      var middlewares;
      middlewares = [];
      middlewares.push( modRewrite( ['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'] ) );
      options.base.forEach( function( base ) {
        return middlewares.push( serveStatic( base ) );
      });
      return middlewares;
    }
```

Otherwise it works great! Helped me a lot!